# Mercurial Queues: combining patches

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I've been playing with Mercurial and mercurial queues, and now have a fairly reasonable working version.  However, before I submit a patch, I'd like to take that spagetti-history and merge it into discrete, logical steps, rather than the semi-overlapping repeated do-undo-redo-slightly-differently mess it is now, if only to reduce the number of patches.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hg qfold` is the way to go. Be very careful with it. Make sure you have read all the [instructions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory?highlight=%28qfold%29) beforehands. It's reasonable to version your patchqueue too (as a nested repoository), so you have backups:

> hg qinit [-c]
>
> init a new queue repository
>
> The queue repository is unversioned by
>   default. If -c is
>       specified, qinit will create a separate nested repository
>       for patches (qinit -c may also be run later to convert
>       an unversioned patch repository into a versioned one).
>       You can use qcommit to commit changes to this queue repository.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Someone else claimed that `hg export ... > combined.patch` would have been just as effective without requiring MQ - is that so?

Comment: With mercurial 1.5 onwards you can also import multiple patches in a row, so no need to combine them in the export though. You'll still need MQ to strip your changes, or you'd need to clone a clean repo and apply the combined patches there, then abandon your branch. Too much work IMHO.